# Checkbook programs for excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, quicken

Are there any good checkbook programs for exel (or other software) that will take a csv file from the bank? The banks now seem to be trying to force you to install a newer version of quicken and possibly pay a monthly fee for downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/):

> GnuCash is personal and small-business
>   financial-accounting software, freely
>   licensed under the GNU GPL and
>   available for GNU/Linux, BSD, Solaris,
>   Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows.
>
> Designed to be easy to use, yet
>   powerful and flexible, GnuCash allows
>   you to track bank accounts, stocks,
>   income and expenses. As quick and
>   intuitive to use as a checkbook
>   register, it is based on professional
>   accounting principles to ensure
>   balanced books and accurate reports.

Comment: I installed this today on win7-64. I can't get it to run unless I give it internet access. It hasn't earned my trust yet.

Comment: Weird. I haven't used it myself, but I heard good things about it. I can't imagine why it would need net access to start. What error are you getting?

Comment: +1 cuz I think gnucash is a good product (I use it), but might be overkill if all you really want is a checkbook register.  I also am curious about the problem Paul noted - never seen that one myself.

Comment: I use windows firewall with a 3-rd party firewall controller. It asks me when new programs try to use the internet. I have to allow gnu-cash and it's companion process in order for the UI to come up. I must have a checkbook type application that does year-end category reports for my taxes. But that's all I need, not quicken -- I hear it's gotten even worse than before. I will continue to investigate gnu-cash since people seem to like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something nice and simple, have a look at [VT cash book](http://www.vtsoftware.co.uk/cashbook/index.htm) (although it is for cheque books rather than ckeck books).